# how to cluster images using kmeans

Tags: python-2.7, markerclusterer, face

I have face images which will be copied into a folder dynamically. I need to remove duplicate faces and show only distinct faces.

**approach 1)**
Initially i tried using LBP approach in which i constructed histogram for every image and copied the imagepath/histogram as key/value in hashtable. started comparing with other image histograms which is cpu intensive operation i.e if i have 1000 histograms i need to compare histogram 1 to all remaining histograms.  Finally this approach was not solving my problem. I was stuck here

**approach 2)** If i can group all similar face images into specific cluster and 
later remove the duplicates iteratively. Please let me know using python how can i use kmeans for unlabelled data.

Thanks
cd

Comment: Are we talking duplicate images, or multiple images of the same person?

Comment: it is multiple images of the same person